# Is it possible to use Flexbox to style a Responsive Feature List

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to build a feature list that is laid out differently on desktop or mobile views. My grid layout has responsive break points.

My question, can this be done with flex-box to build a feature list which looks like the following (see images below).

Is it possible to style using only flexbox and responsive breakpoints to update flexbox? Or do I need two different divs (shown/hidden) per responsive media query layout?

**On Desktop:**

[image]

**On Mobile**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the *exact* use-case for flex-boxes. Your html would look something like this (replacing tags with semantic names for clarity):

```
<featureBox>
   <feature>
       <image/>
       <contentBox></contentBox>
   </feature>
</featureBox>
```

What you want are 2 flex boxes: the `featureBox` and the `feature`. While the `featureBox` will always be in a column, the `feature` will change for desktop.

```
featureBox, feature {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

@media (...) {
   feature {
      flex-direction: row;
   }
}
```